# Remove node from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

While trying to remove a unique node from firebase realtime DB, the node is removing but the same node is created again. Here I am checking for node and if the node is available removing that field
using node `reference.removeValue()`

```
 val query: Query = firebaseDatabase.reference.child("members").orderByChild("resetKey")
            .equalTo(uniqueKey)
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d("snapshot", snapshot.value.toString())
                    for (childSnap in snapshot.children) {
                     
                     val key= childSnap.child("resetKey").value.toString()
                        if (key.isNotEmpty() && key == uniqueKey) {
   firebaseDatabase.reference.child("members")
                     .child(childSnap.ref.key.toString())
                     .child("password")
                     .setValue(password)
      var eMail = childSnap.child("email").value.toString()
                       
                            firebaseDatabase.reference.child("members")
                            .child(childSnap.key!!)
                            .child("resetKey").removeValue()      
                        }else{
                            mCheckUniqueKeyResponse.value = 2
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("error", error.message.toString())
            }
        })
```

Any suggestions accepted.

Comment: This typically happens when your security rules are rejecting the write/delete operation. But it's hard to say more without seeing the [minimal code and rules with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are using for that.

Answer (score 0):

While holding node we can't update/ remove same node.
Because we have instance of queried node.